# Force Apache directory listing even if DirectoryIndex files are present

Tags: apache-2.2, directory-listing

How can I configure Apache to list files in a directory *even if* an index file is present?

For example, if I have a directory `/var/foo` that contains a number of files, and one of those is a directory index (index.html, index.php, etc.), how can I make Apache show the directory listing instead of displaying the contents of index.html, when a user browses to `http://example.com/foo/`?

```
# Directory listing for /var/foo/, mapped to http://example.com/foo/
..
.
code.c
readme.pdf
index.html
```

I have used the following but I would imagine there's a better way:

```
Options +Indexes +MultiViews
DirectoryIndex will-never-exist.xyz
```

Comment: nice question for an starter

Comment: I'm a frequent Stack Overflow user so I know my way around the network. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may leave `DirectoryIndex` option empty or just turn off `dir_module` module.

Comment: Leaving the option empty doesn't work for me with apache-2.2.14, `index.html` still gets used.

Comment: Check your config, it's assigned somewhere. Try to disable module

Comment: @Selivanov: got the same problem (tried both empty `DirectoryIndex ` and quoted empty string `DirectoryIndex ""`, defined at the root of my VHost). But when I specify a non-existent file (or disable the module), it works so it's not overriden somewhere else (AFAICT).

Answer (score 3):

The [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive can be limited in scope with a [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory) block

```
<Directory /path/to/directory/to/list>
    Options +Indexes +MultiViews
    DirectoryIndex will-never-exist.xyz
</Directory>
```

This limits the scope to the particular directory rather than your vhost or server etc.

Comment: My question was how to disable a DirectoryIndex already in effect, not how to limit scope to a directory...

Comment: You should rewrite your question to be clearer about your goal then.

Comment: I think it's worded fairly clear but I'll try to improve it.